# Passing parameter to SPROC that returns location specifc data?

Tags: c#, sql, variables, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure created with a static variable (@Location).
Im trying to create a C# app that will pass the LocationID parameter to the stored procedure. The parameters will need to be passed TWICE (Location1 and Location2). So far all I have is the following code, and I'm not sure how to loop it, or if its written properly?

```
using (Conn)
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_EXAMPLESPROC]",Conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter LocationParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValu("@LocationID", "1");
    LocationParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Comment: Loop what? You just need to add your other parameter.

Comment: Well the reason I need to loop is because I need the SP to run once, pull that data into the app, and then the app will create a file to put the Location1 data into, and then run AGAIN with Location2 parameter (which then will be passed to a different file).

Comment: Or I guess I don't have to loop it, I can just call the method twice? The question now is - how to a write the method that will pass the parameter value to the static variable in the stored procedure?

Comment: I posted an answer to address your question, although I'm not sure which static variable you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry, the "static variable" is the variable in my stored procedure that I am trying to pass a parameter to. Thank you for your help! This definitely put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you put your code into a method called `StoreLocation()`. You'd make it take a parameter `locationId' (is it really a string like you have?) like so:

```
private void StoreLocation(string locationId)
{
    using (Conn)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_EXAMPLESPROC]",Conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter LocationParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", locationId);
        LocationParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Or however your sproc works.
    }
}
```

Then you just call it twice or use a loop or whatever you want:

```
private void SomeCallerMethod()
{
    // Whatever other code you have.

    StoreLocation("1");
    StoreLocation("2");

    // More other code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `LocationID1` and `LocationID2` parameters to stored procedures and then 
do like this

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(@LocationID1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(@LocationID2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "2";
```

this should work

Comment: Thank you! However, the SP only has ONE declared variable (@LocationID). How would I format this code to loop so that it passed both values separately and creates separate data tables with the results? For example, I need the SP to run with LocationID1, store that data in a table, then run again with LocationID2 to fill a different table.